# Search by 2 params

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

```
class Expense < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :expenses
end

class ExpensesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if params[:concept] || params[:category_id]
        search = "%" + params[:concept] + "%"
        @expenses = Expense.where("concept LIKE ? OR category_id = ?", search, params[:category_id])


    else
     @expenses = Expense.order("date DESC")
    end
  end
end
```

Hi, I need to search by 2 params.  Concept is a text_field and category_id is a select_tag.

I am using sqlite3.

I need to get same results for:
http://localhost:3000/expenses

and for:
http://localhost:3000/expenses?utf8=%E2%9C%93&concept=&category_id=

If you want you can use my seeds:

```
restaurantes = Category.create(name: "Restaurantes")
carro = Category.create(name: "Carro")
hogar = Category.create(name: "Hogar")

Expense.create(category: restaurantes, date: Date.current, concept: "Hamburguesas el burral", amount: 32000)
Expense.create(category: restaurantes, date: Date.current - 4, concept: "Hamburguesas el burral", amount: 45000)
Expense.create(category: carro, date: Date.current, concept: "Gasolina", amount: 80000)
Expense.create(category: hogar, date: Date.current - 6, concept: "Lámparas", amount: 350000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Mutate the scope instead of using OR.

```
class ExpensesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @expenses = Expense.order("date DESC")
    if params[:category_id].present?
      @expenses = @expenses.where(category_id: params[:category_id])
    end
    if params[:concept].present?
      @expenses = @expenses.where("concept LIKE ?", "%#{params[:concept]}%")
    end
  end
end
```